# How to save MPMediaItemCollection to database?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, mpmediaitemcollection

I'm making an application that allows user make playlist and edit playlist , using **MPMusicPlayerController**. I already able to make playlist and then retrieve it so it can be played. What I don't know is how can I store **playlist(MPMediaItemCollection)** to core data or any database, So the user could have many playlist.

I've tried this [Play iPod playlist retrieved from a saved persistentid list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702707/play-ipod-playlist-retrieved-from-a-saved-persistentid-list) , But I realize it's can only save one playlist. CMIIW

So how can I save many playlist in core data or NSUserDefaults ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an mutable array add your playlist in that array via `addObject`

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(playlistArray, forKey: "playlists")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Don't forget to fetch the data in array from `NSUserDefaults` before next playlist creation.

Comment: so if I want to make 5 playlist , how can I save it and then retrieve it with every song in the playlist?